# How to compare initial vs latest record in MySql

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to join following three tables in the same query, and trying to get the status basis the initial and the final value.

Table1

```
ID1        Date1                      Value1
T-1        2019-12-15 12:14:13        10000
T-2        2019-12-15 16:17:24        11000
T-3        2019-12-17 10:01:11        15000
T-4        2019-12-18 21:10:21        17000
```

Table2

```
ID2        Date2                      Value2    Seq
T-1        2019-12-16 19:18:11        10000     1
T-2        2019-12-16 16:33:24        12000     1
T-2        2019-12-17 15:21:21        12000     2
T-2        2019-12-17 13:10:18        18000     3
T-2        2019-12-18 19:18:07        11000     4
T-3        2019-12-17 11:11:11        14000     1
T-3        2019-12-18 22:18:08        13000     2
T-3        2019-12-18 19:07:01        13000     3
T-4        2019-12-19 21:38:15        17000     1
T-4        2019-12-19 21:45:20        17000     2
```

Table3

```
ID3         Date3                     Value3
T-1        2019-12-16 19:18:11        10000 
T-2        2019-12-18 19:18:07        11000
T-3        2019-12-18 19:07:01        13000
T-4        2019-12-19 21:45:20        17000
```

As it is clear that `Table3` contains the latest record, I want to derive the below mentioned details using the above tables:

- If the `Value2` where `Seq`=1 is less or greater than `Value1` then show it as a FALSE
- Fetch the Initial Date, where `Seq`=1 and latest date against each unique `ID`

Required Output:

```
ID3     Value1        Value3          Initial_Date           Latest_Date           Status
T-1     10000         10000           2019-12-16 19:18:11    2019-12-16 19:18:11   TRUE
T-2     11000         12000           2019-12-16 16:33:24    2019-12-18 19:18:07   FALSE
T-3     15000         14000           2019-12-17 11:11:11    2019-12-18 19:07:01   FALSE
T-4     17000         17000           2019-12-19 21:38:15    2019-12-19 21:45:20   TRUE
```

I have tried following query but it didn't work: MySQL Version is `5.7.25`

```
select ID3,Value1, Value2, Date2 As Initial_Date, Date3 As Final_Date
from Table1 t1
Left Join Table2 t2 on t1.ID1=t2.ID2
Left Join Table3 t3 on t2.ID2=t3ID3
where t2.Seq=1
group by t3.ID3;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this sample data all you have to do is remove the `group by` clause from your query and the `Status` column like this:

```
select t3.ID3, t1.Value1, t2.Value2, 
  t2.Date2 As Initial_Date, t3.Date3 As Final_Date, 
  t1.Value1 = t2.Value2 Status
from Table1 t1
Left Join Table2 t2 on t1.ID1=t2.ID2
Left Join Table3 t3 on t2.ID2=t3.ID3
where t2.Seq = 1
```

If you want the `Status` column as `TRUE` or `FALSE`:

```
select t3.ID3, t1.Value1, t2.Value2, 
  t2.Date2 As Initial_Date, t3.Date3 As Final_Date, 
  case when t1.Value1 = t2.Value2 then 'TRUE' else 'FALSE' end Status
from Table1 t1
Left Join Table2 t2 on t1.ID1=t2.ID2
Left Join Table3 t3 on t2.ID2=t3.ID3
where t2.Seq = 1
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=070e4d2d0c634d8ba4ac6bfbbf6a442e).
Results:

```
> ID3 | Value1 | Value2 | Initial_Date        | Final_Date          | Status
> :-- | -----: | -----: | :------------------ | :------------------ | :-----
> T-1 |  10000 |  10000 | 2019-12-16 19:18:11 | 2019-12-16 19:18:11 | TRUE  
> T-2 |  11000 |  12000 | 2019-12-16 16:33:24 | 2019-12-18 19:18:07 | FALSE 
> T-3 |  15000 |  14000 | 2019-12-17 11:11:11 | 2019-12-18 19:07:01 | FALSE 
> T-4 |  17000 |  17000 | 2019-12-19 21:38:15 | 2019-12-19 21:45:20 | TRUE
```

Also since you have `where t2.Seq = 1` then the join to Table2 is an Inner join and not a Left join.

Comment: You can check the results in the demo, they are the same as your expected results.

Comment: For the sample data that you posted this code returns the correct results.